# SQL - row that is a combination of rows in another table

Tags: sql, sqlite, architecture

I have a system in which many softwares are running.
Let's say that the system elaborates a pizza from 0 to the cooking.
It has the following subsystems:

1. RecipeWizard: picks selected ingredients.
2. IngredientMixer: Spreads the ingredients on the dough.
3. Oven: cooks the pizza with specific temperature.

Each of these subsystem runs an independent software that can be upgraded independently.
For each pizza, we need to know the different softwares that we used to make it.

For example, pizza n° X was made using RecipeWizard v1.0, IngredientMixer v2.3, Oven v1.1

I've done the following (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE pizza (
  id_pizza INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  something INTEGER NULL,
  ...,
);
```

A software has properties. In this table, there might be several occurrences of a software but with different version or revision. This allows me to know what software have been put in the entire system.

```
CREATE TABLE softwareProperties (
    id_softwareProperties INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(16) NULL,
    version INTEGER NULL,
    revision INTEGER NULL
);
```

The revision (as in SVN revision) of a software is supposed to change very often (2-3 times a day per developper) for testing purposes.

The last table is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS softwareVersion (
  id_softwareVersion INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  fk_pizza INTEGER NOT NULL,
  fk_RecipeWizard  INTEGER NOT NULL,
  fk_IngredientMixer INTEGER NOT NULL,
  fk_Oven INTEGER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT c_01_softwareVersion FOREIGN KEY (fk_pizza) REFERENCES pizza (id_pizza)
  CONSTRAINT c_02_softwareVersion FOREIGN KEY (fk_RecipeWizard ) REFERENCES softwareProperties (id_softwareProperties)
  CONSTRAINT c_03_softwareVersion FOREIGN KEY (fk_IngredientMixer) REFERENCES softwareProperties (id_softwareProperties)
  CONSTRAINT c_04_softwareVersion FOREIGN KEY (fk_Oven) REFERENCES softwareProperties (id_softwareProperties)
);
```

Do you have a better way to do this instead of having multiple foreign keys ?
PS: Let me know if you find a better title for the question.

Comment: I'd start with a many to many relationship between PizzaID and SoftwareId.  If you don't know what that means, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: Ok, before posting the question I was reading about **Identifying Relationship** (found it in MySQL WorkBench) because it seemed to be related to my needs. _About the book, I hope that the comment is not sarcastic. I don't have the time to get and read it, not that I don't want. I'm sure you understand what it's like to have a boss who "need it fixed for yesterday". _

Answer (score 0):

I've looked the many to many relationship. Apparently, I'd have to remove all my foreign key in the softwareVersion table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS softwareVersion (
  fk_pizza INTEGER NOT NULL,
  fk_softwareProperties INTEGER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT c_01_softwareVersion PRIMARY KEY (fk_pizza, fk_softwareProperties),
  CONSTRAINT c_02_softwareVersion FOREIGN KEY (fk_pizza) REFERENCES pizza (id_pizza)
  CONSTRAINT c_03_softwareVersion FOREIGN KEY (fk_softwareProperties ) REFERENCES softwareProperties (id_softwareProperties)
);
```

The problem is that, for each pizza, this table will have as many rows added as there are distinct software. In this case, there will be 3 rows for each pizza.

So, the ideal case would be having 1 pizza, 1 row in the junction table, this row would refer to a unique group of softwares.
Is there a design pattern for that ?